# Join 2 class in one query with common Foreign key

Tags: python, django

My model:

```
class Doc(models.Model):
    numdoc = models.CharField(max_length=14)

class DocQT(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Doc, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='doc_qt')
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_length=14)

class DocDate(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Doc, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='doc_date')
    date_cons = models.DateTimeField(defalt=date.today())
```

Now, i need to order by date_cons and get quantity using che common foreign key to join the classes.

Something like:

```
myquery= [...]
for member in myquery:
```

i need to render:

```
member.quantity
```

and

```
member.date_cons
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that using a `ForeingKey` here means that there can be many dates and quantities for each `Doc` instance.

One solution is to join the data in the view (Python code):

```
doc_dict = {}
for e in DocQT.objects.select_related('doc').order_by('doc_id', 'quantity'):
    if e.doc_id not in doc_dict:
        doc_dict[e.doc_id] = {
            'doc_obj': e.doc,
            'docqt_list': [],
            'docdate_list': [],
        }
    doc_dict[e.doc_id]['docqt_list'].append(e.quantity)
for e in DocDate.objects.select_related('doc').order_by('doc_id', 'date_cons'):
    if e.doc_id not in doc_dict:
        doc_dict[e.doc_id] = {
            'doc_obj': e.doc,
            'docqt_list': [],
            'docdate_list': [],
        }
    doc_dict[e.doc_id]['docdate_list'].append(e.date_cons)

# raise error if there isn't one per doc
# for _, v in doc_dict.items():
#     if len(v['docqt_list']) != 0:
#         raise ValueError(
#             'doc {} has more or less than one quantity'.format(v['doc_obj'].id))
#     if len(v['docdate_list']) != 0:
#         raise ValueError(
#             'doc {} has more or less than one date'.format(v['doc_obj'].id))

# sort by date
result_list = list(
    sorted(
        doc_dict.values(),
        key=lambda x: x['docdate_list'][0]))
```

Then in the view you could do:

```
{% for v in result_list %}
    {{ v.doc_obj.id }}
    {{ v.doc_obj.numdoc }}
    {{ v.docqt_list.0 }}
    {{ v.docdate_list.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```